# Select from table while run insert query on that table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I am trying to run a stored procedure that grabs data from some tables and shows that data to the user while running another query that inserts data to that same table that I am grabbing the data from.

In the end my query that grabs the data from the server looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS row, 
         ManualJEListTempTable.* 
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber,
              dbo.ManualJEHeader.JEType,
              dbo.JEType.Description as JETypeDescription,
              --dbo.ManualJELines.JELineNo,
              dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId,
              dbo.Companies.CompanyName,
              dbo.ManualJEHeader.OrginalCurrency,
              --dbo.ManualJELines.DebitAmount,
              --dbo.ManualJELines.CreditAmount,
              (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ManualJELines.DebitAmount, 0)) from ManualJELines where (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode not like 'CA' or  dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode is null) and companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId and dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) as totalDebitAmount,
                  (select  sum(isnull(dbo.ManualJELines.CreditAmount,0)) from ManualJELines where (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode not like 'CA' or  dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode is null) and companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId and dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) as totalCreditAmount,
                  (select  sum(isnull(dbo.ManualJELines.ConsolidationDebitAmount,0)) from ManualJELines where (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode not like 'CA' or  dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode is null) and companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId and dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) as totalConDebitAmount,
                  (select  sum(isnull(dbo.ManualJELines.ConsolidationCreditAmount,0)) from ManualJELines where (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode not like 'CA' or  dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode is null) and companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId and dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) as totalConCreditAmount,
                  (select  sum(isnull(dbo.ManualJELines.TransactionDebitAmount,0)) from ManualJELines where (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode not like 'CA' or  dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode is null) and companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId and dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) as totalTranDebitAmount,
                  (select  sum(isnull(dbo.ManualJELines.TransactionCreditAmount,0)) from ManualJELines where (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode not like 'CA' or  dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode is null) and companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId and dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) as totalTranCreditAmount,
                 -- dbo.ManualJELines.ItemCode,
                  --dbo.ConsolidationItems.ItemName,
                  --dbo.ManualJELines.AccountNo,
                  ---ISNULL(dbo.Accounts.AccountName,'') as accountName,
                 -- dbo.ManualJELines.ContraItemCode,
                 -- ISNULL(contraItem.ItemName,'') as ContraItemName,
                --  dbo.ManualJELines.ContraAccountNo,
                 -- ISNULL(ContraAcountName.AccountName,'') as ContraAccountName,
                --  dbo.ManualJELines.ContraCompanyId,
                --  ISNULL(compName.CompanyName,'') as ContraCompanyName,
                    dbo.ManualJEHeader.JEReference,
                    dbo.ManualJEHeader.Details,
                  dbo.ManualJEHeader.BalanceDate,
                  dbo.ManualJEHeader.StatusCode,
                  dbo.JEStatus.Description as statusDescription,
                  dbo.ManualJEHeader.StornoDate
            from dbo.ManualJEHeader with(nowait)
            --inner join dbo.ManualJELines
            --on dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId = dbo.ManualJELines.CompanyId and dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = dbo.ManualJELines.JENumber
            inner join CompaniesGroupDetails with(nowait) on dbo.CompaniesGroupDetails.CompanyId = ManualJEHeader.CompanyId
            inner join CompaniesGroupHeader with(nowait) on dbo.CompaniesGroupHeader.GroupId = CompaniesGroupDetails.GroupId
            left join Companies with(nowait) on ManualJEHeader.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId
            --left outer join Companies with(nowait) compName on ManualJELines.ContraCompanyId = compName.CompanyId
            --left join ConsolidationItems with(nowait) on dbo.ManualJELines.ItemCode = ConsolidationItems.ItemCode
            --left outer join ConsolidationItems with(nowait) contraItem on dbo.ManualJELines.ContraItemCode = contraItem.ItemCode
            left join JEStatus with(nowait) on ManualJEHeader.StatusCode=JEStatus.StatusCode
            --left join Accounts with(nowait) on ManualJELines.AccountNo=Accounts.AccountId and ManualJELines.CompanyId = Accounts.CompanyId
            --left outer join Accounts with(nowait) ContraAcountName on ManualJELines.ContraAccountNo = ContraAcountName.AccountId and ManualJELines.CompanyId = ContraAcountName.CompanyId
            left join JEType with(nowait) on ManualJEHeader.JEType=JEType.TypeCode where CompaniesGroupHeader.GroupId = '00' and (dbo.ManualJEHeader.StatusCode <> 'CA' or dbo.ManualJEHeader.StatusCode is null)) as ManualJEListTempTable ) as tempTable where Row between 0 and 300
```

And when I run this query, I get this error

> Msg 1222, Level 16, State 51, Line 3
>   Lock request time out period exceeded.

Does anyone have any idea why I got that error while using `with(nowait)`?

Comment: That's a lot of subqueries in that statement; you'll likely be better off with a `JOIN` for performance. Also, using the schema of the table when referencing a column is deprecated and should be avoided. You really really should be aliasing your objects for readability, as it's (in my opinion) a bit of a mess at the moment

Comment: Idea: The purpose of the `nowait` hint is to provide that error rather than waiting for a locked resource. ([Explanation](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SqlNoWait.aspx).) Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. That may help us improve the performance of your query in order to minimize conflicts over resources. DDL and indexes would also help. Are the index statistics up-to-date?

Comment: If you feel comfortable with my answer, then you should mark it as accepted, but you should also pay attention to the risks involved. Never use it in delete, insert or update statements and follow  @Larnu hints.

Answer (score 0):

How long does your query run ? if you are using no wait then probably you have to use 
`'SET LOCK_TIMEOUT timeout_period'` option in beginning of the query.

```
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 1400 (which is in 1400 milliseconds)
```

You can see this too (this blog has really good explanation on how to understand nowait with set lock_timeout) https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/28/sql-server-basic-explanation-of-set-lock_timeout-how-to-not-wait-on-locked-query/

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
With(nolock)
```

After each join or table and you are done.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Person.Contact WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ContactID < 20
```

Be careful when you use this.
[read this on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190805(v=sql.105))

If you have to deal with solution, you also have to deal with possible issues like:

**Lost Updates**
Lost updates occur when two or more transactions select the same row and then update the row based on the value originally selected. Each transaction is unaware of the other transactions. The last update overwrites updates made by the other transactions, which results in lost data.

**Uncommitted Dependency (Dirty Read)**
Uncommitted dependency occurs when a second transaction selects a row that is being updated by another transaction. The second transaction is reading data that has not been committed yet and may be changed by the transaction updating the row.

**Inconsistent Analysis (Nonrepeatable Read)**
Inconsistent analysis occurs when a second transaction accesses the same row several times and reads different data each time. Inconsistent analysis is similar to uncommitted dependency in that another transaction is changing the data that a second transaction is reading.

**Phantom Reads**
Phantom reads occur when an insert or delete action is performed against a row that belongs to a range of rows being read by a transaction.

**Missing and Double Reads Caused by Row Updates**

Comment: If you're going to suggest `NOLOCK`  you should really warn the OP all the problems/caveats that come with it. Otherwise the OP could well start having problems with the reliability of the data returned from their statement; especially as the problem is that there are DML statements being run against the table(s).

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Larnu it is up to the user to deal with this. If the result isn’t important than why not?    And it has solved the op question. Thanks for the downvote

Comment: How does very possibly incorrect data "solve" the problem? If you're saying it's up to the user to deal with it, why does this answer not cover what the users *needs* to do, or not warn them there is additional work to do to ensure the result set is correct? This far from solves the problem the OP when kt a different problem, that could be far worse. From experience, having no data, which can be obtained later, is far better than having inaccurate data that you haven't been warned is inaccurate.

Comment: If you detail the warnings that come with `NOLOCK` this could very well be a solution for the OP, if they don't care about accuracy (which I doubt, but you never know), but right now it could put them in a worse position.

Answer (score -2):

i rewrite my query with the `with(nolock)` and get what i want,

this is my final query

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS row,
             ManualJEListTempTable.*
      FROM (SELECT dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber,
                   dbo.ManualJEHeader.JEType,
                   dbo.JEType.Description AS JETypeDescription,
                   dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId,
                   dbo.Companies.CompanyName,
                   dbo.ManualJEHeader.OrginalCurrency,
                   (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ManualJELines.DebitAmount, 0))
                    FROM ManualJELines WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode NOT LIKE 'CA'
                        OR dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode IS NULL)
                      AND companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId
                      AND dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) AS totalDebitAmount,
                   (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ManualJELines.CreditAmount, 0))
                    FROM ManualJELines WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode NOT LIKE 'CA'
                        OR dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode IS NULL)
                      AND companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId
                      AND dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) AS totalCreditAmount,
                   (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ManualJELines.ConsolidationDebitAmount, 0))
                    FROM ManualJELines WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode NOT LIKE 'CA'
                        OR dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode IS NULL)
                      AND companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId
                      AND dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) AS totalConDebitAmount,
                   (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ManualJELines.ConsolidationCreditAmount, 0))
                    FROM ManualJELines WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode NOT LIKE 'CA'
                        OR dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode IS NULL)
                      AND companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId
                      AND dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) AS totalConCreditAmount,
                   (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ManualJELines.TransactionDebitAmount, 0))
                    FROM ManualJELines WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode NOT LIKE 'CA'
                        OR dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode IS NULL)
                      AND companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId
                      AND dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) AS totalTranDebitAmount,
                   (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ManualJELines.TransactionCreditAmount, 0))
                    FROM ManualJELines WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE (dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode NOT LIKE 'CA'
                        OR dbo.ManualJELines.statuscode IS NULL)
                      AND companyId = dbo.ManualJEHeader.CompanyId
                      AND dbo.ManualJEHeader.JENumber = JENumber) AS totalTranCreditAmount,
                   dbo.ManualJEHeader.JEReference,
                   dbo.ManualJEHeader.Details,
                   dbo.ManualJEHeader.BalanceDate,
                   dbo.ManualJEHeader.StatusCode,
                   dbo.JEStatus.DESCRIPTION AS statusDescription,
                   dbo.ManualJEHeader.StornoDate
            FROM dbo.ManualJEHeader WITH (NOLOCK)
                 INNER JOIN CompaniesGroupDetails WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.CompaniesGroupDetails.CompanyId = ManualJEHeader.CompanyId
                 INNER JOIN CompaniesGroupHeader WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.CompaniesGroupHeader.GroupId = CompaniesGroupDetails.GroupId
                 LEFT JOIN Companies WITH (NOLOCK) ON ManualJEHeader.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId
                 LEFT JOIN JEStatus WITH (NOLOCK) ON ManualJEHeader.StatusCode = JEStatus.StatusCode
                 LEFT JOIN JEType WITH (NOLOCK) ON ManualJEHeader.JEType = JEType.TypeCode
            WHERE CompaniesGroupHeader.GroupId = '00'
              AND (dbo.ManualJEHeader.StatusCode <> 'CA'
                OR dbo.ManualJEHeader.StatusCode IS NULL)) ManualJEListTempTable ) tempTable
WHERE ROW BETWEEN 0 AND 300;
```

pay attention that i write `with(nolock)` after every table (when i didn't do that the query was still lock)

Comment: I refer to the comments I made on @MattOpen 's answer. Also, *if* `NOLOCK` really is the answer, with all the caveats it comes with, you should be marking MattOpen's answer as the solution. but i still strongly suggest you understand the implications of `NOKOCK` first.

Comment: You also still have the schema referencing here in your column; which really needs to go.